# Merging many tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-outer-join

Suppose there are the following three PostgreSQL tables to be merged with the common ID column.

```
table A  
ID V1
2  100
3  200
4  250

table B
ID V2
1  200
3  140

table C
ID V3
2  90
3  100
4  10
5  200
```

I would like to merge these three tables as follows:

```
merged table
ID V1   V2   V3
1       200  
2  100       90
3  200  140  100
4  250       10
5            200
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the id column only once in the result, the obvious choice would be an equijoin with the `USING` clause:

```
SELECT id, v1, v2, v3
FROM   a 
FULL OUTER JOIN b USING (id)
FULL OUTER JOIN c USING (id)
```

This way you also don't need `COALESCE` at all - which gets messy with lots of tables quickly.

[**-> SQLfiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a22a1/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
    select A.*,B.V2,C.V3
    from 
    A 
    full outer join B on A.id = B.id
    full outer join C on C.id = coalesce(A.id,B.id)
```

Comment: Note - I haven't tested this.

Comment: Doesn't quite work as is. It needs `COALESCE()` for the `id`.